# The challenges of learning when there are no tasks

Tags: teaching

I like exactly this format:

```
Knowledge -> Task -> Knowledge -> Task
```

And the knowledge is required to do the following task. Not more. Not less. Therefore you know that the task is solvable and you do have enough knowledge. In other words:

```
Knowledge1 -> Task(requires only Knowledge1) -> Knowledge1+Knowledge2 -> Task(requires only Knowledge1+Knowledge2)
```

How do you call this method of teaching?

Books and courses that I see are all the same:

```
Knowledge -> Knowledge -> Knowledge -> Knowledge -> Knowledge -> Knowledge -> Knowledge -> End.
```

I think I have to read till the end, even summarize in mindmaps, just to realize later that I have no idea where to start.

Therefore I need to create my own tasks in between.

But I don't know whether how I solve my tasks is accurate.

How could I handle this?

Comment: In what discipline are you studying?  In many, it's common for textbooks to have exercises and for courses to have homework.

Comment: French currently.

Comment: This method of teaching is called “scaffolding”

Answer (score 1):

I think you could propose for yourself such a task solution of which you could publish in some community.

For example, if you're studying French, you could translate something form French to your native language and publish on Medium

Answer (score 1):

Studying languages can be difficult because many natural sentence constructions use “difficult” language in their everyday use. But since language often doesn’t use “easy” language, it’s imperative that you learn it anyways. There are a few strategies that I have found helpful:

1. **Manufacture “easy” language**, such as by doing textbook exercises
2. **Find organically occurring “easy” language**, such as by consuming media meant for children (picture books, television, etc.)
3. **Familiarize yourself with “difficult” language**, such as by listening to the radio in your target language
4. **Keep track of what you know** on notecards (or whatever method you prefer) because you might discover that you’ve seen “difficult” language before even when you’ve been learning “easy” stuff

Learning a language seldom falls into neat boxes, but learning how to use parts of many boxes at a time will make you great. For example, you don’t need to memorize *every* preposition to be able to use prepositions.

Read. Write. Speak. Listen.